# Octopus deploy not including exe.config in nuget

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am using dbup for my database migration and my dbup project in visual studio solution definitely produces required exe and exe.config file. Now when I deploy my project through octopus deploy I have no exe.confog file in nupkg generated by octo however I can confirm that exe.config is in the release folder on the server.

I found that octopus had a bug with similar issue https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/970 which is resolved now. in version 2.5.1 (https://octopus.com/downloads/compare?from=2.2.1&to=3.4.10) and I am using octopus version 3.3.17 , however I am facing same behaviour..
Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks.

Comment: R u using Octopack nuget for deploying or the octo.exe?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `MSBuild myProjectFile.csproj /p:RunOctoPack=true` inside the project folder, you will see some *OctoPack* logging showing you what it did exactly. It will tell you where it put all the files, which *.nuspec* file was used, etc. Maybe that'll clear some things up.